# Is there a way to draw data from github to oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, github, oracle-apex

I'm creating an app using **Oracle APEX** and I also created a file on **GitHub** with some data in it, can I use the web source module feature of GitHub to draw those data from GitHub because when I try to connect them and I type the URL I get this message ---> Discovery error: Application Express cannot compute a data profile from the response data of type: text/html; charset=utf-8. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of file is it, a JSON file? Is your URL pointing to the raw github file link? e.g. `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...`

Comment: It's a JSON file yes https://github.com/p14para/dik/blob/master/jason

Comment: Yeah, you see the "Raw" link there? Try using that. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/p14para/dik/master/jason

Comment: @kfinity Works like a charm thanks a lot!!! Could I use something like that to take data from excel files??